Finding the Steady-State Solution of the Burgers' Equation
I am trying to determine the steady-state solution of the following Burgers' equation:
\begin{equation*}
u_t+u u_x=\nu u_{x x}, \quad u(x, 0)=\sin (\pi x)
\end{equation*}
subject to the boundary conditions $u(0, t)=u(1, t)=0$.
Could someone provide guidance on how to find the steady-state solution for this equation? Any tips or references for solving such problems would also be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Set $u_{t} = 0$, note that $uu_{x} = \left( \frac{1}{2} u^{2} \right)_{x}$, integrate once with respect to $x$, then separate and integrate again, then apply the boundary conditions.

An alternative to solving the differential equation $uu_x=\nu u_{xx}$, as proposed by Matthew Cassell, is to use the energy method. Multiplying both sides of the Burgers' equation by $u$ and integrating from $0$ to $1$, we get
$$
\int_0^1uu_t\,dx+\int_0^1u^2u_x\,dx=\nu\int_0^1uu_{xx}\,dx. \tag{1}
$$
The first integral yields
$$
\int_0^1uu_t\,dx=\int_0^1\partial_t\!\left(\frac{u^2}{2}\right)dx
=\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1\frac{u^2}{2}\,dt; \tag{2}
$$
the second,
$$
\int_0^1u^2u_x\,dx=\int_0^1\partial_x\!\left(\frac{u^3}{3}\right)dx
=\left.\frac{1}{3}u^3\right|_0^1=0, \tag{3}
$$
and the third,
$$
\int_0^1uu_{xx}\,dx=\underbrace{uu_x\big|_0^1}_{=\,0}-\int_0^1u_x^2\,dx. \tag{4}
$$
It follows from $(1)$-$(4)$ that
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1\frac{u^2}{2}\,dx=-\nu\int_0^1u_x^2\,dx. \tag{5}
$$
In the steady state, the "energy" $E(t):=\int_0^1\frac{u^2}{2}\,dx$ doesn't change with time. This implies, according to Eq. $(5)$, that $\int_0^1u_x^2\,dx=0,$ hence $u_x=0$, or $u=\text{constant}$. Due to the boundary conditions, that constant must be equal to zero. Therefore, the steady-state solution is $\boxed{u=0}.$
